# Getting wrong country dialCode in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub, dart-null-safety

I'm trying the get current country code as per this [plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/country_codes). Right now I'm in India but getting the USA country dialCode.

[image]

So what can I do for getting current country dialCode?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your device is set to the "en-US" locale. It cannot magically determine you are physically in India, you have to set it to "en-IN" if you want that.

What kind of phone it is, whether it is an emulator or not and where exactly you set the device locale is something we don't know. You will have to figure that out.

Comment: Thank you for respond
Yes, I have change the my device language to Hindi after that it's work but when i select the my device language English than not working. So I don't want the select Hindi language in my device, So what can I do for this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a physical device set up for India and not an emulator on a device with another region. Follow these steps.

On main or first screen of app call

```
await CountryCodes.init();
```

and then access country code by

```
final CountryDetails details = CountryCodes.detailsForLocale();
_countryCode = details.dialCode ?? '+1';
```

hope this helps you. If not, let me know I use this plugin often.